# Why does this file reading is asynchronous ?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Suppose I have txt file with content  - `1st print` .

I have this file reading program  -

```
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'file.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        if(reader.status === 200 || reader.status == 0) {
        console.log(reader.responseText);
        }
    }
}

loadFile() ; 
console.log("2st print");
```

and when I run it I get asynchronous result  -

```
2nd print
1st print
```

**Whereas**

The follow program gives synchronize result -

```
function readTextFile(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    console.log(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }


    readTextFile("file.txt");
    console.log("2nd print");
```

result -

```
1st print
2nd print
```

What cause to the asynchronous in the 1st program ?

Comment: May be the 3rd boolean parameter here, `rawFile.open("GET", file, false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the resource.

Refer [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()).

3rd argument in `open` function is to set `sync`

`void open(
   DOMString method,
   DOMString url,
   optional boolean async,
   optional DOMString user,
   optional DOMString password
);`

`true` for asynchronous, and `false` for synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

The third argument to [`open`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method) is whether the XHR object should work asynchronously (`true`) or synchronously (`false`). The latter has the negative effect of locking up the UI of the browser while the request is being handled, so is best avoided whenever possible (and it's essentially always possible).